# How to run 'sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock' on Ubuntu, before the services start

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu Server 16.04, with a service that needs this permission

```
$ sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Right now, every time the server is rebooted, it's necessary to open a ssh console, run that task and start the service manually.

I need to run that command *before the services being started*. What would be the most secure way to do it?

**EDIT:** The service's account already is member of the `docker` group.

Comment: Why not add the service user's account to your `docker` group?

Comment: If you really must have a service using the Docker socket, use a privileged container. But try to avoid it entirely, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, just add the following content to a file called `/etc/init/docker-chmod.conf` to get your permissions set during boot.

```
start on startup
task
exec chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

But you should consider adding your, or a system user, to the `docker`-unix group to avoid workarounds like this which could be a big potential security threat.

The result of your chmod practically gives all local users read and write permissions to the docker-socket which allows anyone to interfere with your docker images.